# Iphone core graphic, mask

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I have a problem with the core graphic of iPhone. Below is a drawing which demonstrate this problem:

[image]

There is a mask with a human shape, I'm put the mask upon an image, I'm doing *"something"* (this is the part I need help with), I remove the mask, and finally the image became human-shape transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution from the apple sample code called QuartzDemo.